# SQL exercises/queries with sample database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am looking for some sample SQL exercises/query (preferred MySQL, or SQLServer)to practice. It would be great if it is with some sample database.

Could someone please point to sql exercises for Sakila Database( MySQL Sample Database) or exercises with some other sample database.

I have already came across
http://courses.cs.tau.ac.il/0368-3458/databases201213a/assignments/hw1.pdf

and looking for more.

Thanks in advance,
Sambhav

Comment: Check this site http://sql-ex.ru/ It has a lot of sql exercises from beginner level to incredibly complex.

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/welcome this is pretty good read on indexes

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a lot out there! Here are a few nice ones that offer (online) practice:

- [SQLZOO](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SQL_Tutorial) - lets you practice interactively with SQL queries for different database management systems;
- [SQLCourse.com](https://www.sqlcourse.com/) - also an interactive tutorial that lets you
  practice SQL queries;
- [Introduction to Databases](https://online.stanford.edu/courses/soe-ydatabases-databases) - a Stanford online course with a lot
  of explanatory video lectures. It is much more theoretical, but also
  provides the possibility to practice with the stuff that's taught. (This course seems now to have been chopped up into 5 different smaller courses.);
- [GalaXQL](https://sol.gfxile.net/galaxql.html) - another interactive SQL tutorial using SQLite;
- [SQL-EX](https://www.sql-ex.ru/) - seems to provide SQL exercises, but requires an
  account.

Some sample databases can be downloaded here:

- SQL Server 2008/2012/2014 -> [AdventureWorks](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks) sample databases;

Comment: Came across this one as well http://www.webucator.com/tutorial/learn-sql/simple-selects.cfm in the process of checking this

Comment: Great the information is looking good :)....currently in the process of analyzing it. Thanks Josien for sharing